# Catch EJBTransactionRolledbackException before it is logged to file

Tags: java, logging, jboss, ejb

My setup:

I have an EJB bean (deployed in an ear on a JBoss 6.4) with a method that calculates some values and stores it in a database. The method is started in a new transaction. It looks like this:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void doStuff() {
    MyObject value = calculateSomeValues();

    entityManager.merge(value);
    entitiyManager.flush();
}
```

By design, it is possible that the flush will fail due to a `ConstraintViolationException`. As this is a new transaction, the exception will be wrapped in an `EJBTransactionRolledbackException` and thrown as a `RuntimeException`. I have set up logging for ejb exceptions as it is useful to find them in the whole system. However as I know that the ConstraintViolationException will occur now and then, I would like to catch it and rollback before the logging system logs it as an error (the constraint violation is not seen as an exception, but it is required from the database's point of view). At the moment, my log file is clogged with entries like this one:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default-threads - 49) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component
```

How can I catch the exception in such a way that the logger is prevented from printing these errors? (Note: I still want it to log all other `EJBTransactionRolledbackException`s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have JBoss 6 deployed, so I cannot immediately test whether the precise exception types work also for JBoss 6 (I tried this on WildFly 8).

A possible solution is to put in your EJB a method annotated by @AroundInvoke (at least if you don't have other interceptors on this EJB):

```
   @AroundInvoke
   public Object myConstraintViolationInterceptor(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception
   {
      try {
          return ctx.proceed();
      }
      catch(PersistenceException e) {
          if (e.getCause() instanceof org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException) {
              //some action taken
          }
          else {
              throw e;
          }
          return null;
      }
   }
```

By the way, if your ConstraintViolationException is actually optimistic locking exception in disguise (that is, it is thrown because another user has modified some data in the meantime), maybe it is better to report it to the user.

Comment: Super! This works! Eventually I ended up creating my own `UserTransaction` so that I could handle specific cases myself, but that is just another way of doing exactly what you described.